# Using pre_get_posts to filter one loop in a multiloop archive

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pre-get-posts

I have a custom-post-type archive (archive-rg_blog.php) with two loops in it. One of the loops I'd like to filter with the below code. It's just a basic loop for all posts, and I just need to set it to return all posts instead of the custom posts it'd return by default.

The other loop needs to pull the title and content from a specific custom post. The below seems to be filtering the second loop too, and so that it returns nothing at all.

```
function blog_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('rg_blog')) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
```

And this is the loop that returns nothing:

```
<?php // blog title and description query
$post_id = 4606;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;?>
<h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>
```

Edit: Just to clarify, this is what I'm trying to do.

```
///loop 1, queries a specific post
///loop 2, a normal loop filtered with pre_get_posts, which should return all posts.
///loop 3, also queries a specific post
```

So I need to add the filter before loop 2, and remove it again before loop 3. I've tried to add the filter into the archive template in the appropriate place, but loop 2 then fails to return all posts.

Edit #2: Here's the whole loop in action. It's the SECOND loop that needs to be filtered.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php // blog title and description query
$post_id = 4606;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;?>
<h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>

<!-- Main Loop (All Posts)   -->
<?php function blog_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('rg_blog')) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!--Featured Post-->
<?php $c++;
if( !$paged && $c == 1) :?>
<!--stuff-->
<!--Other Posts-->
<?php else :?>           
<!--the remaining posts-->          
<?php endif;?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<!-- The end of the loop   -->
<?php remove_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');?>

        <!--third loop, a repeat of loop 1-->  
<?php // blog title and description query
$post_id = 4606;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;?>  
                <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>
                <?php echo $queried_post->post_content;?>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: I know I pointed you down this road in a previous question, but the premise of what you're doing here is flawed. first, your `pre_get_posts` action and function go in your theme's `functions.php`. the main query runs before the template is loaded, so nothing will happen if you try to apply it in the template. HOWEVER- changing the post type of the main query will cause the query to no longer be a custom post type archive, so your `archive-rg_blog.php` template will never get loaded. Can you not do what you want by simply creating a page and making that the posts page under settings > reading?

Comment: Maybe. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

Add the filter where you need it and [remove it afterwards](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
// your query; presumably WP_Query
// your first loop
remove_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
// another query; presumably WP_Query
// your second loop
```

You can also make your action self-removing:

```
function blog_filter($query) {
  remove_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('rg_blog')) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
```

Your code, reorganized:

```
// define the function; can be here or functions.php
function blog_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('rg_blog')) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}

get_header(); 

  // blog title and description query
  $post_id = 4606;

  // add the filter
  add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter'); 

  $queried_post = get_post($post_id);

  // remove the filter; the query is done
  remove_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter'); 

  $title = $queried_post->post_title; ?>
  <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1><?php

  // Main Loop (All Posts)
  $post = $posts[0];
  $c=0;
  if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
      the_post(); 
      // Featured Post
      $c++;
      if( !$paged && $c == 1) {
        // stuff 
        // Other Posts
      } else {           
        // the remaining posts          
      }
    }
  }
  // The end of the loop
  // third loop, a repeat of loop 1

  // blog title and description query
  $post_id = 4606;
  $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
  $title = $queried_post->post_title; ?>  
  <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1><?php 
  echo $queried_post->post_content;
get_footer();
```

I have not tested that but I think it will work better. Hopefully, I don't have any syntax errors.

Edit:

I took a closer look at your code (while not watching "Defiance") and notices a couple of things.

1. Your filter will only effect the main query so you will need to add
   it before the page template loads-- probably in `functions.php`. But
   my understanding of the question is that the filter is meant for a
   secondary Loop. That would mean that that "main query" check is
   wrong.
2. You are requesting posts via `get_post` by ID, so for those the
   filter is irrelevant.

So, to filter that main query you need this in `functions.php`:

```
// define the function; can be here or functions.php
function blog_filter($query) {
  // remove the filter; the query is done
  remove_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('rg_blog')) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'book');
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
```

And no add or remove actions anywhere else. I am not sure that is what you want though. The two `get_post` calls should be unaffected.

Comment: I am trying to add and remove the filter where needed, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I register the function in the functions.php file and then add the filter in the archive file, or does the whole thing go in the archive file?

Comment: See my edit above, which clarifies exactly what I'm trying (and failing) to do.

Comment: See the edit, and post all of your code so I can see it in context.

Comment: Okay, see my new edit.

Comment: Like said, you have to add the filter before the query. Give me a minute to reorganize that.

Comment: thanks for your help but the filter just isn't working. If I put the whole thing (including the add_action) in the functions.php file, it filters the query for this archive but all three queries. If I try to put all of this in the archive template itself, it doesn't filter any of the queries. I don't know if it will help, but here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/QgS72Y5H) to a pastebin of the entire template file, including html.

Comment: The main query (the one in the middle, without the page ID) should call ALL posts. But it's in a custom post archive template, which is why I need the filter. By default, that post will pull all CUSTOM posts in that archive, but I want it to pull all the regular posts. (My reasons for setting things up this way are questionable, but this is the goal...) So if I set up the filter the way I originally had it, in the functions file, the main query does what I want it to do, but the two secondary queries (which pull a page ID) then do nothing. That is, they don't return any titles or content.

Comment: And thanks for all the time you've spent trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the `is_post_type_archive` before adding the filter:

```
global $wp_query;
if ($wp_query->is_post_type_archive('rg_blog')) {
    add_action('pre_get_posts','blog_filter');
}
```

This way, it won't run on every page load.

---

Try removing the filter before the second query:

```
remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'blog_filter');
```